# Joining pandas DataFrames by Column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two DataFrames with the following column names:

```
frame_1:
event_id, date, time, county_ID

frame_2:
countyid, state
```

I would like to get a DataFrame with the following columns by left-joining on `county_ID = countyid`:

```
joined_dataframe:
event_id, date, time, county, state
```

I cannot figure out how to do it if the columns on which I want to join are not the index.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

You can use the `left_on` and `right_on` options of [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) as follows:

```
pd.merge(frame_1, frame_2, left_on='county_ID', right_on='countyid')
```

Or equivalently with [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
frame_1.merge(frame_2, left_on='county_ID', right_on='countyid')
```

---

I was not sure from the question if you only wanted to merge if the key was in the left hand DataFrame. If that is the case then the following will do that (the above will in effect do a many to many merge)

```
pd.merge(frame_1, frame_2, how='left', left_on='county_ID', right_on='countyid')
```

Or

```
frame_1.merge(frame_2, how='left', left_on='county_ID', right_on='countyid')
```

Comment: To expand on this a little, if you want to specify an index on one side, you can use `right_index=True`.

Comment: @Woody What if `frame_1` already has `county_ID` as index, and `frame_2` already has `countyid` as index? I understand I can substitute `frame_1.reset_index()` for `frame_1` (and same for `frame_2`) in your answer. But is there a more efficient way to join/merge without resetting index?

Answer (score 6):

you need to make `county_ID` as index for the right frame:

```
frame_2.join ( frame_1.set_index( [ 'county_ID' ], verify_integrity=True ),
               on=[ 'countyid' ], how='left' )
```

for your information, in pandas left join breaks when the right frame has non unique values on the joining column. see this [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5391).

so you need to verify integrity before joining by `, verify_integrity=True`

Answer (score 0):

Merging using differently named columns duplicates columns; for example, after the call `frame_1.merge(frame_2, how='left', left_on='county_ID', right_on='countyid')`, both `county_ID` and `countyid` columns are created on the joined frame but they have exactly the same values for every row, so presumably only one of them is needed. To not have this problem from the beginning, rename the merge-key column be the same and merge on that column.

```py
df1 = frame_1.rename(columns={'county_ID':'county'})
df2 = frame_2.rename(columns={'countyid':'county'})
joined_frame = df1.merge(df2, on='county', how='left')
```

[image: res1]

Also, if the second frame has only one new additional column (e.g. `state`) as in the OP, then you can map that column to `frame_1` via the common column.

```py
frame_1['state'] = frame_1['county_ID'].map(frame_2.set_index('countyid')['state'])
```

If `county_ID` and `countyid` were **indices** (not columns), then a straightforward `join` call does the job. By default, it performs left join.

```py
joined_frame = frame_1.join(frame_2)
```

[image: res2]

One nice thing about `join` is that if you want to join multiple dataframes on index, then you can pass a list of dataframes and join efficiently (instead of multiple chained `merge` calls).

```py
joined_frame = frame_1.join([frame_2, frame_3])
```