# Can pandas join tables if the common headers are different names?

Tags: python, pandas

I am following this article, but I was only able to get it to work by making sure there were matching titles, the two still had computer names, but they were called differently in the title, how could I modify my command so that it still references the same column, is that possible?

```
lj_df2 = pd.merge(d2, d3, on="PrimaryUser", how="left")
```

For example, I have this, but on my other csv, I have `Employee #` not `primary user`

Comment: You mean different left and right on values? `lj_df2 = pd.merge(d2, d3, left_on="PrimaryUser", right_on="Employee #", how="left")`

Comment: @HenryEcker you should post that as an answer

Comment: It's a duplicate if that's the answer [Joining pandas dataframes by column names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20375561/15497888) @AngusL'Herrou

Comment: @HenryEcker true.

Comment: This is also discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101 (first answer ... do ctrl+F and search for "Different names for key columns")