# How to concat panda dataframes so that they are sorted by year?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have 2 df's

One simply just contains index and year such as:

| (index) | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 |
| 2 | 2001 |
| 3 | 2002 |
| 4 | 2003 |

Then I have a dataframe that consist of index, year, and some other datapoint such as:

| (index) | Year | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2001 | 1.515 |
| 2 | 2003 | 2.631 |

How do I join them so that I only transfer over the relevant 'data' column and it properly aligns with the dates 2001 and 2003 in the 1st dataframe? Of-course I will be using this method to import many more columns.  e.g:

| (index) | Year | data | different data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 |  | potato |
| 2 | 2001 | 1.515 |  |
| 3 | 2002 |  | pickle |
| 4 | 2003 | 2.631 |  |

Comment: this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375561/joining-pandas-dataframes-by-column-names

Comment: @JDornheim So left_on and right_on would = "Year" ? That just ends up being the 2nd DF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a left merge:

```
>>> df = df.merge(df2, how='left')
>>> df
   Year   data
0  2000    NaN
1  2001  1.515
2  2002    NaN
3  2003  2.631

# Optional:
>>> df = df.fillna('')
   Year   data
0  2000       
1  2001  1.515
2  2002       
3  2003  2.631
```

Comment: That was actually way easier than I had thought... Works perfect.. I don't know why but it just does.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {"Year": [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003]}
data2 = {"Year": [2001, 2003], "data": [1.515, 2.631]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer", on="Year")
df = df.fillna("")

df
```

Returns

[image]